How do I create a Webhook in Azure so I can load data into a Datalake?
I apologize if my question is worded poorly, but I've been searching online for a few hours now and I keep running into dead ends and working on something until realizing it's not what I need.
I was wondering if anyone had any good resources for creating a Webhook in Azure for loading data? What tool in Azure should I be using to make the Webhook? I have a vendor who will be sending POST calls to the Webhook once I build it to send data that I need to drop into a datalake or into a Synapse Data Warehouse.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Can you provide what approach that you have tried so far?

@RakeshGovindula honestly so far I've tried following the instructions for a few different tools, not realizing they were the wrong thing to build a Webhook for, such as DevOps (the web hooks there I believe are designed for Git related changes). I'm currently trying to see if I can do it in the API Management Service, but I'm currently stuck at the Web Service URL (what is that?) step of making one. Building APIs is totally new territory for me, and I can't for the life of me find any sort of examples of other people doing Webhooks in Azure for this purpose online anywhere.

Are you still facing the issue. @Jwest

@Jahnavi Yes I am. I put in a ticket with Microsoft support regarding the issue, but the only answer I've been able to get so far is that I can not make a web hook using Azure API Management Service and need to use another tool. I still don't know what that tool is.

Let me check and update you a workaround. @Jwest

You can try Azure function apps as a workaround here in this case.
Go to Azure portal -> Create Azure function app. You can select the Runtime stack as per your desired language. Here, I have chosen python function app. Give the same region as your storage account and set this as the function app storage account.
In the function app, go to functions overview and create a new function of HTTP trigger type.

You can select the Authorization level as Function or Anonymous as per your security requirements.

After creating the Azure function, use the python code from this documentation to upload the file to your Data Lake. You can also refer this SO answer by @Rithwik Bojja.
Now, if your function app authorization is Function level, generate the function app key and you can give this key to your clients.

For sample, I have used the URL, and you can see the return response.


The task for this got reassigned off me at work but I'll forward this to whoever has to do it next. Thanks!
